# Generating an array of random variables (positive and negative) that sum up to 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I am trying to create a numpy array with random variables that sum up to 1, but I also want to include negative values.

I am trying:

```
size =(50,1)
w = np.array(np.random.random(size))
```

to create the array and populate with numbers (negative and positive), and this works fine.

Now I am trying to make them sum up to 1 with:

```
w /= np.sum(w)
```

But this changes my values to be all positive (eliminating the negative values).

What is the proper way to do an array like this?

Edit: I already tried random.int and random.uniform, but the problem is that those don't sum up to 1. and if I use  `w /= np.sum(w)` to make sure they sum up to one, it just returns positive values.

Comment: `random.random` won't give you negative values and dividing by `np.sum` won't change the sign of your values (except it's negative, then it will change it for all values).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edit the OP to include what I already tried. I tried random.uniform (since I want float values). But dividing by np.sum() did change all my values to positive for some reason (I have no idea why)

Comment: `np.random.random(size)` always gives positive numbers in the range `(0,1)`.  It's not your `sum` that's the problem, it's your random generator.

Comment: @DanielF Yes wou are absolutely correct. I changed the OP to include that I also used np.uniform to give me the values.

Comment: Just to clarify - marginal distributions won't be uniform. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't your normalization, it's your random generator.  `np.random.random` always generates positive floats from `(0,1)`.  If you want negative numbers, you'll have to change that.

```
w = np.random.random(size)*2-1
w /= w.sum()

w

array([[ 0.05377353],
       [ 0.11272973],
       [ 0.00789277],
       ..., 
       [ 0.06874176],
       [-0.12505825],
       [-0.15924267]])

w.sum()
 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used k = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(n,1)) and
    k /= k.sum() and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function specifically for this task but you can generate an array (2d preferably) based on your expected size then choose those that sum up to 1.

Here is an example:

```
In [18]: arr = np.random.randint(-10, 10, (50, 5))

In [19]: arr[arr.sum(1) == 1]
Out[19]: 
array([[  9,  -9,   1,   5,  -5],
       [-10,   5,  -4,   9,   1],
       [  1,  -2,   5,   3,  -6]])
```